# how to make a text box accept number only [like 8, 3.5, 6.5.5] in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

How to make a textbox in angular accept only numerical values or decimals, valid formats of no 8, 3.5, 6.5.3 etc. I've tried

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="VersionNumber" />
```

but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Please provide some code first

Comment: forgot to add code properly. Updated

Comment: Just look at the example in [AngularJS Input Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).

Comment: @AndreaM16, you didn't read my question correctly. If i enter something like 6.5.3 it is invalid as a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex validation on the input with `ng-pattern` html attribute.

`ng-pattern="/^\d+\.?\d*$/"` or `ng-pattern="versionRegex"`

Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ftw01zv7/

I have included a couple of other regular expressions you could potentially use. Just find the right one for your case.